# If $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ and $(N_t)_{t\ge0}$ are stochastic processes, what is the filtration generated by $\left(Y_{N_t}\right)_{t\ge0}$?

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, filtrations

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ and $(E,\mathcal E)$ be measurable spaces
- $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ be a $(E,\mathcal E)$-valued stochastic process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$
- $(N_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a $\mathbb N_0$-valued stochastic process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$

Don't know if it matters, but in my application, $Y$ is a Markov chain and $N$ is a Poisson process, independent from $Y$.

Moreover, let $$\mathcal F^N_t:=\sigma(N_s:0\le s\le t)\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0$$ and $$\mathcal F^Y_n:=\sigma(Y_m:m\in\left\{0,\ldots,n\right\})\;\;\;\text{for }n\in\mathbb N_0.$$

Now, let $$X_t:=Y_{N_t}\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0$$ and $$\mathcal F^X_t:=\sigma(X_s:0\le s\le t)\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0$$

> How can we show that $$\sigma\left(\left\{A\cap B\cap\left\{N_t=n\right\}:A\in\mathcal F^N_t,n\in\mathbb N_0\text{ and }B\in\mathcal F^Y_n\right\}\right)=\mathcal F_t:=\sigma(\mathcal F_t^N\cup\mathcal F_t^X)$$ for all $t\ge0$?

Let $t\ge0$. I even fail to show that if $A\in\mathcal F^N_t$, $n\in\mathbb N_0$ and $B\in\mathcal F^Y_n$, then $A\cap B\cap\left\{N_t=n\right\}\in\mathcal F_t$. Though, it would be clear, if $B\cap\left\{N_t=n\right\}\in\mathcal F^X_t$. I guess we somehow need to use that $X_t$ coincindes with $Y_n$ on $\left\{N_t=n\right\}$.

Comment: One condition I guess should be that $Y_m\neq Y_{m+1}$ a.s. otherwise there is no way one can see the time when $N_{t}=m+1$ occures.

Comment: @RaphaelB4 It should hold in general. Please take a look at p. 164 of [Ethier/Kurtz](https://www.academia.edu/23372547/Markov_Processes_Characterization_and_Convergence). They write that the claim holds by the Dynkin class theorem. (BTW, it would be helpful if I could at least show that $N_{s+t}-N_s$ is independent of $\mathcal F^X_s$, which seems intuitively plausible. Do you have any idea regarding that?)